# telegram Url Button example code with php

Tags: button, inline, telegram

can anybody give me example of telegram URL Button?

i dont now hot to use inlinekeyboradButton and Url Bottun.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton

please help me and give me very simple php code

Comment: please help  me ... just one example code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class, representing the InlineKeyboardButton: [InlineKeyboardButton.php](https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot/blob/0ebd95c40797ffff2faefd58e3734ca905f1606b/src/Entities/InlineKeyboardButton.php)

Example usage:

```
<?php
    $btn = new InlineKeyboardButton([
        'text' => 'Example text',
        'url' => 'http://example.org'
    ]);
```

As simple, as that.

Comment: thank you but I dont want use external class.